# Segmentation Fault while printing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "string.h"
//This function tries to calculate result of the floor function for floats <= 9999.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int i, j;
float k;
int x[10000];

for(i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    x[i] = i;
}

printf("Enter a float in 0..9999: ");
scanf("%f", &k);

tester(x, k);
 }

int tester(int* c, int k) {
printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, c[k]);
}
```

When I run the program it gives me segmentation fault in here:

```
printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, c[k]);
```

Can anyone see the what problem really is?

You can see the screenshots:
[segmentation fault in printf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZPJR.png)

Comment: `k` is an `int`, which you can print with `%d` or `%i`, but not with `%f`.

Comment: I have changed but it gives same error

Comment: Have you dealt with all of the compiler warnings?

Comment: Well, what's the value of `k` you entered? Did `scanf` succeed? What's the value of `k` in `tester`?

Comment: The *first* warning you should get is concerning an implicit declaration of an otherwise-previoiusly-unknown function `tester` assumed to be `int tester()`. That spells trouble, because that means you can pass near anything (including nothing) to the `tester` function call in `main` and your program will accept it. Since you are implementing `tester` *after* `main`, yet calling it from `main` you need a *prototype* announcing its existence (or just move the definition before `main`). Once you do that, more warnings will begin popping up, all of which are errors and should be handled.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you are entering float values (0.66 and 0.99). What do you expect to happen when using those values as an index to your array? An array index can only be integer (whole numbers). Maybe you're missing a rounding?

Comment: actually you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems in your code.

1. You get input from the user (scanf) as **float**, but actually use it as **int** to pass it into the function and as index for the array `x`.
2. You should **ALWAYS** check user input from the terminal (or wherever). In this case the check should be at least, if the actual input is between 0 and 9999.

Improved version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "string.h"

void tester(int* c, int k) {
    printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, c[k]);
}  

//This function tries to calculate result of the floor function for floats <= 9999.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    int k;
    int x[10000];
    
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
        x[i] = i;
    }
    
    printf("Enter a float in 0..9999: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    if (k >= 0 && k < 10000) {
        tester(x, k);
    } else
    {
        printf("Sorry, your input %d was invalid.", k);
    }
}
```

Probably that will fix your Segmentation Fault problem.

Comment: Now it gives same error for this line:
    if (k >= 0 && k < 10000)

Comment: Can you test your program here: https://cplayground.com/.
It should run fine. What type/version of c++ compiler and debugger are you running?